How do Madara live so long?
I don't get how he lived so long yes he had the white zetu but how were they made who made them and why? Was I just for Madara or something I don't follow I mean I get it for the plot but other than that how? Did Orochimaru help him live so long knowing him he would...

Welcome to anime and manga SE! Please read the Code of Conduct and Site Tour. Also please consider becoming a regular member around here, as its always nice to have new folks around.

@AustinOverton Quick tip: if you type [tour] in a comment, it generates a link to the [tour] (like so), in case the user doesn't know where to find it. [help] links to the [help] as well.

@F1Krazy Oh, that's good to know, thanks!
